# Check which child is in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, css

After I check which child is in the viewport I would like for **that** child to get some class ('child-animate'), and then when the next child comes in viewport I would like for **that next** to get class ('child-animate') and so on.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<script>
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = (elementTop + $(this).outerHeight()) * .9;
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = (viewportTop + $(window).height()) * .75;

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
</script>
```

I tried something like this:

```
if ($('.parent .child').isInViewport()) {
    $(this).addClass('child-animation');
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: @Joundill I don't know does this change anything but this condition is triggered $(window).on('scroll', function(){ } For some reason it does not work. It only works when I add specific class of element, like $('.child').addClass('child-animation'); but not on $(this).
My original code: 
```$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($sectionTechnology.isInViewport()) {
      $sectionTechnology.addClass('section-technology-animation');
    }
    if ($('.section-portfolio .wrap').isInViewport()) {
      $(this).addClass('wrap-animation');
    }
  });```

Comment: Try recreate your problem in a code sample in your question so we can see it.

Comment: Check what does `this` contains in this scope and what are the arguments of the callback function according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd use an IntersectionObserver. I've created a simple version that you can see here.

```js
const children = document.querySelectorAll(".child");

observer = new IntersectionObserver( (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach (entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      // console.log(entry.target.innerHTML + " is visible");
      entry.target.classList.add("animate");
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove("animate");
    }
  });
});

children.forEach( child => {
  observer.observe(child);
});
```

```css
.child {
  height: 120vh;
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate {
  animation: fade-in .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(25px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child1</div>
    <div class="child">Child2</div>
    <div class="child">Child3</div>
    <div class="child">Child4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it answers your question, please mark it answered so that people with the same issue will find it. :)